# How do I properly set link variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, hyperlink

I have 4 buttons which create a text output, so that a "Go" button goes to the link given in that text output. 
I'm still a javascript noob and am thinking in other languages, but is there a way to make .innertext into a variable based on last button pressed? This is the best logic I've come up with, and would like to make it more efficient code.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<h1 id="changedText">Button changes this text</h1>


<button onclick="btn1()">Button1</button>
<button onclick="btn2()">Button2</button>
<button onclick="btn3()">Button3</button>
<button onclick="btn4()">Button4</button>
<br>

<button onclick="Go()">Go to Link Above</button>



<script>
function btn1() {
document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = "http://www.test- 
button-1.com";
}
function btn2() {
document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = "http://www.test- 
button-2.com";
}
function btn3() {
document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = "http://www.test- 
button-3.com";
}
function btn4() {
document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = "http://www.test- 
button-4.com";
}
</script>
```

As you can see my code is really dirty, and doesn't "Go" to the link, what am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function setLink(link) {
  document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = link;
}

function Go() {
  document.location.href = document.getElementById("changedText").innerText;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="changedText">Button changes this text</h1>


<button onclick="setLink('http://www.test-button-1.com')">Button1</button>
<button onclick="setLink('http://www.test-button-2.com')">Button2</button>
<button onclick="setLink('http://www.test-button-3.com')">Button3</button>
<button onclick="setLink('http://www.test-button-4.com')">Button4</button>
<br>

<button onclick="Go()">Go to Link Above</button>
```

Comment: I have added the Go function, but for some reason my entire javascript breaks. Now, I'm not getting any text changed. Does this have to do with the source?

Answer (score 0):

Just single click handle that.No need to define 4 function.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var siteId = $(this).text().slice(-1);
  var url = "http://www.test-button-@.com";
  if (!isNaN(siteId)) {
    url = url.replace(/@/gi, siteId);
    $(this).text(url);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button1</button>
<button>Button2</button>
<button>Button3</button>
<button>Button4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var url = $(this).data("url");
  $("#changedText").text(url);
  $("#goButton").data("url", url)
});
$("#goButton").click(function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).data("url");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="changedText">Button changes this text</h1>

<button data-url="http://www.test-button-1.com">Button1</button>
<button data-url="http://www.test-button-2.com">Button2</button>
<button data-url="http://www.test-button-3.com">Button3</button>
<button data-url="http://www.test-button-4.com">Button4</button>

<button id="goButton">Go to Link Above</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? I'm a bit puzzled at how this is working.

Comment: When you click on any button with "data-url" attribute (read more about this attribute here: https://api.jquery.com/data/)  JQuery read this attribute (this line: var url = $(this).data("url");) and render it inside element with id "changedText" (this line: $("#changedText").text(url);)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using input tag and whenever click on a button, you assign the value properties to a global variable.
Then, "Go" function will change your text as:

```
    function Go(){
      document.getElementById("changedText").innerText = `http://www.test-${globalVariable}.com`;
    }
```